# Delphi Toolbar Style Changed

Tags: delphi, button, toolbar

I just upgraded from Delphi 2009 to Delphi XE8. Doing so has changed the appearance of the buttons on the toolbar of my program.

When compiled with Delphi 2009, it looked like this:
[image]

But now with Delphi XE8, it looks like this:
[image]

It seems to me that this is related to the Down property. If a Down property of a button is true, then its background will be blue. If I click on the button then that will change the Down property to false and the button will lose the blue background.

Does anyone know what might be causing the blue background and how I can eliminate it?

I am on Windows 8.1.

---

Followup:  David's answer that this is the default display for Windows 8.1 is correct. Checking other programs, I see they do this as well.

I wasn't expecting this to be the default because my program compiled with Delphi 2009 didn't do this. But as David also explained, that's because Delphi 2009 did not have built in theme support, but Delphi XE8 does. (It may have been added in Delphi XE2, but don't quote me on that)

David's mentioned the manifest as a possible cause. It wasn't in this case, but he alerted me that I may have multiple manifests and should check for it.

So the final answer to my question is that I don't want to eliminate the blue background. It is the Windows 8.1 default way of displaying Down buttons, and I want to display the native theme by my program.

Comment: Is one version themed and the other not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I do not use themes. My program from Delphi 2009 was simply run in Delphi XE8 (after fixing only what needed fixing to get it to work). The Toolbar is a simple TToolbar, and each Button is a simple TToolButton. I did not make any changes to the form. I can provide some of the relevant DFM text if that will help.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I did a test: I added a new TToolbar. I added a few TToolButtons to it. In the Object Inspector for a ToolButton, I set Down to true and the background became blue. I unchecked Down setting it back to false and the blue disappeared.

Comment: Is the app themed? Do you have the comctl32 v6 manifest?

Comment: I just rediscovered a question I asked a few years ago and maybe my "solution" to that then is involved. I shall investigate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890805/how-can-i-implement-highlighted-toolbar-icons-with-delphi?rq=1

Comment: I think I answered the question that you asked as best as could be done with the information in front of me. I think it's not fair for you to belatedly mention that you are using a modified toolbar control.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - See my accepted answer to that question. I'm pretty sure that's what I went with, which is not a modified toolbar control, but I'll have to check at home to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your D2009 program is not themed, but your XE8 program is themed. By that I mean that the XE8 includes an application manifest that specifies version 6 of comctl32. Your D2009 program does not include a manifest, or does not include that part of the manifest which requests comctl32 version 6.

The visual appearance of the XE8 program is the native platform appearance, and on the face of it, it would be normal to follow the platform's lead. So the option that I would opt for is to leave the appearance as the platform standard. That is go with the XE8 version.

However, to answer your question, you can revert to the old appearance by removing the comctl32 v6 part of the manifest. This will affect other parts of your program too. If you only want to disable themes for the toolbar, that can be achieved with `SetWindowTheme`.

Comment: Thank you David. You've given me some things to investigate and I'll comment again once I've tried everything. I did have a manifest in my Delphi 2009 files which I added to get Windows certification. If Delphi XE8 is adding one of its own, then I may have two and that's bad. Also, this question may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855988/ancient-delphi-vcl-app-looks-to-have-no-windows-theme-or-vcl-style

Comment: Just having a manifest is one thing. The contents of the manifest matter. Clearly one app is themed and the other not. That can be seen from the images.

Comment: So far, I have not noticed any other differences in styling. Only the TToolButtons look different and only when their Down property is true. I will investigate the manifests, but something is still fishy here.

Comment: You do understand though that the blue highlighting is the platform native style and, all things being equal, is the look you should be aiming for.

Comment: Actually, no I didn't. I thought this was a caused by my code or in the Delphi VCL. I had never noticed that styling before in Windows 8.1. When I get home, I'll check to see whether other programs I have show that styling, and I'll set up a new program for testing. But what you say makes sense, since a new TToolButtton on a new TToolbar had the blue background. However, wouldn't my Delphi 2009 compiled program then change its styling as well? It doesn't.

Comment: ... and its such an ugly styling, I couldn't imagine that the Windows 8.1 people would have implemented that. Down should just look pushed in, and shouldn't be a different color.

Comment: *However, wouldn't my Delphi 2009 compiled program then change its styling as well?* I explained why it doesn't in my answer. Because the D2009 app is not themed.